# Find the sum of all values of spinners with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of spinners `<select>` input fields and I want to find the sum of them live.  I figured the easiest way would be to use jquery's class selector but it does not store the `.val()`'s of elements of a similar class in an array.

Is there a way to store all the values of a bunch of `<select>` Inputs in an array so I can find the sum of all of their values.

My not working code looks like this.

```
function calcPrice() {
     var price = $('.food').val() || [];
}
$("select").change(calcPrice);
```

Comment: Should the question tag be javascript instead of java?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Java. "Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be overkill, but you could use http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm

or you could simply do:

```
var price = 0.0
$(".food'").each(function() { 
   price += +this.value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to clarify what are the `.food` elements? Are they input fields? Otherwise, you may want to try using `$('.food').text()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to btiernay's answer, but if you wanted to keep the actual array you can do:

```
var prices = $.map($(".food"), function () {
   return +this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var expenses = 0.0;
$(".expense").each(function() { 
      expenses += +this.value;
});
$("#expense-total").html(expenses);
```

Basically the same as btiernay but it has missing ; which could fool noobs.  Also added jquery element example to push the final value to a sum field.  Sorry I could't add as a comment as I rarely post so reputattion less than 50.

Live example under business expeses here: http://contractor.icalculator.info/calculator/PAYE-calculator.html